# I tried deleting records by id, but it happens, I have found the last record is deleted

Tags: laravel-5.3

I tried deleting records by id, but it happens, I have found the last record is deleted,

```
//Index method just
Report::all( ) ;

//Delete mesthod
Report::delete($id);
```

sorry if very quick question, I use a mobile phone now
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, one should find the specific record with a query and perform delete on that.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#deleting-models

Based on their example your code should be more like:

```
$record = Record::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have observers which fire on `Record` delete then you should use Model's `delete()` method as:

```
Record::find($id)->delete()
```

Or you can just use query builder's delete method as:

```
Record::where('id', $id)->delete()
```